# Can a private github repo be synced with pythonaywhere

Tags: github, hosting, pythonanywhere

I want to sync a Django project with pythonanywhere. But the Django repo is private is it possible to do so. So, that the deployment is up to date with the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You could set ssh key-pair on your PythonAnywhere account and add it to your GitHub account. Then pull your code on the PythonAnywhere side and re-load your web app.

You could also automate the whole process. See the tutorial: https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/191/